# ACF and differencing order of operations

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, autocorrelation

When calculating ACF and PACF, what is the rule regarding differencing?  For example, I have an increasing time series- looking at instrument drift.  Differencing returns what looks like white noise.  When I do ACF and PACF, do I use the raw values or the differenced values?

I've done both, just playing around.  The raw values return positive ACF values for many lags.  The differenced values return a negative value and the rest negative and insignificant.

What is the correct procedure? Since the mean increases over time.  Do I difference before ACF?  Or ACF on the raw data?

Comment: Beware of overdifferendcing. Differencing is only appropriate when the original series are integrated, but not otherwise. Mean increasing over time does not warrant differencing, but rather modelling with a deterministic (e.g. linear) time trend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You look at ACF and PACFs of the differenced series. This is because these are tools for looking at *stationary* processes. You mention that the undifferenced values have a mean increasing over time...right off the bat that process can't be stationary.

Looking at the ACF and PACF will help you distinguish between some sort of noise and an ARMA(p,q) process. If you're looking at financial time series, it would be unsurprising to see ACF and PACF values that look nonsignificant--white noise is a pretty common model. Also keep in mind that stationarity can be broken in more ways than the mean function depending on time.

Edit: Valerie, what Richard is referring to might happen if your true model is something like $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \epsilon_t$ where $\epsilon_t$ is iid or white noise. In this case, if you incorrectly difference your series, you will have $\bigtriangledown y_t = \beta_1 + \epsilon_t - \epsilon_{t-1}$. Then, looking at the ACF plot, it will look like you have an MA(2) model. This will help you determine whether the series is trend-stationary or difference-stationary, or in other words, if it has a deterministic trend or a stationary trend.

Comment: Thanks, new to this method, so I appreciate the non judgement.  Also gives me more to base my next searches on.

Comment: In general, I would advise someone new to time series like this: Beware of overdifferendcing. Differencing is only appropriate when the original series are integrated, but not otherwise. Mean increasing over time does not warrant differencing, but rather modelling with a deterministic (e.g. linear) time trend.

Comment: @RichardHardy How do you tell if it is "over differencing".  If as OP says, the original data has an upward trend and looks non-stationary. After differencing it one time, it pass the stationary test (e.g.ADF test). Does it mean the differencing is the right thing to do or does it not?

Comment: @Taylor If the model is that linear model, after differencing and then use the ARIMA(0, 1, 2) model, does it have any problem?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse, ADF test is a test of a unit root of autoregressive type, not a test of stationarity. Overdifferending yields a unit root of the moving-average type which goes undetected in an ADF test. Differencing is not appropriate unless there is a unit root of AR type. My comment above says that modelling with a deterministic (e.g. linear) time trend should be tried instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy If a time series pass ADF test, does it have any obvious reason to differenciate? If not, should it fair to say if the series pass ADF, then no differencing. If failed ADF, then differencing it will be justified and no worry about over differencing?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse, there is no point in using the ADF test unless you are dealing with a process that may have a unit root. A time series without a unit root but with a deterministic trend may fail the ADF test (unless the trend is accounted for in the test specification), but that does not imply the series should be differenced.

Comment: @RichardHardy Suppose I have a time series, I fed it to ADF test, it failed. After differencing, it pass the ADF test. Or if I don't differencing but set the regression parameter  `regression='ct'` or `regression='ctt'`, it pass the test. What does this tell us?

Comment: @anoffercan'trefuse, you should check the existing questions tagged with [tag:augmented-dickey-fuller], your questions have most likely been answered there.